# Show parent taxonomy term in view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have *taxonomy* **countries list** with cities

```
Czech Republic
 - Prague
 - Brno
Germany
 - Berlin
```

Then I have content type **position** where I am using this taxonomy as select list. Now I need to create table with list of this content type.

Wanted result:

```
Country       || City
--------------||------
Germany       || Brno
Czech Republic|| Prague
```

I have created view for that, but I am not sure how to show parent of taxonomy term.

I have found that [How to show the parent and child taxonomy term?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28076/how-to-show-the-parent-and-child-taxonomy-term) but I do not see **Taxonomy term: Term ID**, **Taxonomy term: Parent term** at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- First you need to create a *Taxonomy term on node* relationship to your vocabulary and name the identifier *term*
- Then create a *Taxonomy term: Parent term* relationship using the previous identifier (*term*) as relationship and name the identifier  *parent*
- Create a *Taxonomy term: Parent term* contextual filter using *term* as identifier
- Lastly, add a *Taxonomy term: Name* and use the *parent* relationship

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. I have one additional question. Is it possible to access user only child terms from taxonomy in content? To allow only to select city, not country.

Comment: Hi @Dawe I would recommend you to accept the answer(+1) if that worked for you, as it will be helpful for others as well to pick up an already accepted answer. Also post one question at a time, in case you have unrelated queries, post them as separate question. As far as your question is concerned for term access tsa module(https://www.drupal.org/project/tsa) should do the job for you.

Comment: Thank you  arpitr. Unfortunately I am not able to add +1 to answer, because of small reputation