# How to display taxonomy terms parents along with child terms in views block?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, taxonomy-terms

I have taxonomy terms structure something like below:

```
 - Parent 1
    - Child 1
    - Child 2
    - Child 3

 - Parent 2

 - Parent 3
    - Child 4
    - Child 5
```

I want to display same structure in a views block. I already [reviewed in this link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28076/how-to-show-the-parent-and-child-taxonomy-term) . They have not used blocks. They used pages and depend upon url argument they did something. But I need this to be display in a block. I searched some of the suggestions by using contextual filters and relations but not able to get this structure. Please give some other suggestion which you have used in your case. thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already look into that answer. In this link which you mentioned, they have not used blocks. They used pages and depend upon url argument they did something. But i need this to be display in a block.

Comment: Check the second answer by Llouieliu in the same question - he does not use url parameters.